# Pin a wordpress version on wp-cli

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

I am using `wp-cli` to download WordPress

```
wp-cli --allow-root core download
```

Is there some way to pin the WordPress version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./wp-cli.phar --version=5.9.2 --allow-root core download
```